# How could I syncronize this method execution from the same class so that only 2 executions at a time are possible

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

**Introduction**

I did this project for homework and got it rejected because it was not what the teacher wanted even if it gave the desired result.

My code executes two runners, but it needs EVERY runner(Thread) started since the beginning.

**Problem**

A relay race between two teams (4 runners each) start with all the participants ready at start of the simulation. The output must be similar to this:

```
Equipo 1 Corredor Alfonso preparado 
Equipo 2 Corredor Manolo preparado 
Equipo 2 Corredor Martín preparado 
Equipo 2 Corredor Matías preparado 
Equipo 2 Corredor Marcos preparado 
Equipo 1 Corredor Antonio preparado 
Equipo 1 Corredor Armando preparado 
Equipo 1 Corredor Alberto preparado 
Equipo 1 [ Alfonso ]: 13m 
Equipo 2 [ Manolo ]: 9m 
Equipo 1 [ Alfonso ]: 23m 
Equipo 2 [ Manolo ]: 18m 
Equipo 1 [ Alfonso ]: 34m 
Equipo 2 [ Manolo ]: 28m 
Equipo 1 [ Alfonso ]: 47m 
Equipo 2 [ Manolo ]: 39m 
Equipo 1 [ Alfonso ]: 58m 
Equipo 2 [ Manolo ]: 48m 
Equipo 1 [ Alfonso ]: 67m 
Equipo 2 [ Manolo ]: 61m 
Equipo 1 [ Alfonso ]: 80m 
Equipo 2 [ Manolo ]: 71m 
Equipo 1 [ Alfonso ]: 93m 
Equipo 2 [ Manolo ]: 82m 
Equipo 1 [ Alfonso ]: 100m 
Equipo 2 [ Alfonso ]: pasa el testigo 
Equipo 2 [ Manolo ]: 91m 
Equipo 1 [ Alberto ]: 109m 
Equipo 2 [ Manolo ]: 100m 
Equipo 2 [ Manolo ]: pasa el testigo 
Equipo 1 [ Alberto ]: 120m  
...
Equipo 1 [ Antonio ]: 398m 
Equipo 2 [ Martín ]: 383m 
Equipo 1 [ Antonio ]: 400m 
Equipo 2 [ Martín ]: 393m 
Equipo 2 [ Martín ]: 400m 
Marca del equipo 1: 38,08s
Marca del equipo 2: 39,08s
```

**My attempt on this problem is:**

Main.class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Atleta atleta1 = new Atleta("Manolo");
        //Atleta atleta2 = new Atleta("Cresencio");

        String[] nombresEquipo1 = new String[] {"Manolo", "Cresencio", "Obundio", "Recardo"};
        String[] nombresEquipo2 = new String[] {"Eusebio", "Americio", "Legasov", "Yokése"};

        Atleta atleta1 = new Atleta(nombresEquipo1);
        Atleta atleta2 = new Atleta(nombresEquipo2);



        Thread equipo1 = new Thread(atleta1);
        Thread equipo2 = new Thread(atleta2);

        equipo1.setName("Equipo 1");
        equipo2.setName("Equipo 2");

        //Run ma bicthes
        equipo1.start();
        equipo2.start();
    }
}
```

Carrera.class

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Atleta implements Runnable{

    private List<String> nombresEquipo = new ArrayList<>();
    private String nombre;
    private int recorrido;
    private int velocidad;


    public Atleta(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Atleta(String[] nombresEquipo1) {
        this.nombresEquipo = Arrays.asList(nombresEquipo1);
        this.nombre = this.nombresEquipo.get(0); //Load first name
    }

    public int generateRandom(int min,int max) {
        return min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
    }

    public void setVelocidad(int velocidad) {
        this.velocidad = velocidad;
    }

    public void setRecorrido(int recorrido) {
        this.recorrido += recorrido;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Carrera carrera = new Carrera();
        int i = 0;

            try {
                //synchronized (carrera) {
                while (carrera.getMeta() < 400) {
                    setVelocidad(generateRandom(9, 14));
                    setRecorrido(this.velocidad);
                    carrera.correrHaciaMeta(this.velocidad);
                    if (this.recorrido >= 100) {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " [ " + this.nombre + " ] Velocidad: " + this.velocidad + " Recorrido: " + "100" + " Cursa: " + carrera.getMeta());
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " [ " + this.nombre + " ] " + "pasa el testigo.");
                        i++;
                        this.nombre = nombresEquipo.get(i);
                        this.recorrido = 0;
                    } else if (carrera.getMeta() >= 400) {
                        System.out.println("Fin de la cursa!");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " [ " + this.nombre + " ] Velocidad: " + this.velocidad + " Recorrido: " + this.recorrido + " Cursa: " + carrera.getMeta());
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("[ERROR] " + e);
            }

    }
}
```

Carrera.class

```
public class Carrera {

    private int meta = 0;

    /**
     * Recorre una distancia segun la velocidad
     * */
    public void correrHaciaMeta(int velocidad) {
        this.meta += velocidad;
    }

    public int getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }
}
```

Equipo.class

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Equipo {

    private String nombreEquipo;
    private List<String> nombres;

    public Equipo(String nombreEquipo, String[] nombres) {
        this.nombreEquipo = nombreEquipo;
        this.nombres = Arrays.asList(nombres);
    }
}
```

**TL;DR**

I need help in "How to syncronize the execution so that only 2 runners are running when every Thread is told to run"

**Notes**

- IDE: IntelliJ
- Java version: 12
- No external libraries needed
- The code works

EDIT:

**Further Explanation**

All the runners must start at the same time but only 2 of them, from each team, should be running till they run a 100 meters.

That means that there must be a thread for each Runner and output:

```
Team-[1 or 2] Corredor [Name] is ready.
```

Comment: By "two runners" do you mean one runner each from each `nombresEquipo` 1 & 2?

Comment: Also can you explain this further: `My code executes two runners, but it needs EVERY runner(Thread) started since the beginning` What did your teacher say was wrong here?  Are you only supposed to be using two threads, not "every thread"?

Comment: @markspace I was supposed to use every Thread at the same time, a Thread is a Runner.

Comment: You'll probably have to explain more what is needed.  There are ways of doing this but they're pretty complicated, esp. if you can't use the concurrent library built-in API.  I'm not sure what you or your teacher are asking to be done here.

Comment: It looks like the purpose of the exercise was to have one thread for each athlete, (8 in total) where every athlete is in one of the following states: preparing, waiting to run, running, finished running.   You currently only have 2 threads, one for each team.

Comment: @HAL9000 and I'm not really understanding how I can manage it. I know I have to use the 'syncronized(this)' (which is commented) but not sure how I can make one of each team run.

Comment: @markspace All I need to use it's run all the threads (athletes) at the same time but only 2, of each team, run at the same time till a 100 meters, the others wait for the relay. The race ends at 400 meters. Neither I know what the teacher is asking, that is why I am here.

Comment: @HAL9000 Read the problem again, he has two teams of *relay* race runners.  I'm pretty sure that the second runner (thread) in each team is supposed to wait on the first, and so on.  The OP's implementation is really lacking.  WhiteGlove: you need to make a better effort and talk to your instructor.  Besides `synchronized(this)` you also need to learn what `wait()` and `notifiy()` do.

Comment: @markspace, If you only have one thread per team, (two threads in total), the athletes can not prepare themselves in parallel. And doing a relay in a loop doesn't serve any purpose if the exercise is to learn how to synchronize threads. Besides the the explanation says there should be one thread per runner, and there are eight of them.